# C++ Place data member in linker section

Tags: c++, c, linker

Consider a setup where a microcontroller has limited SRAM and a larger (external) SDRAM.
I am writing a class that has a number of data members that should reside in the fast SRAM and a large buffer (just an array) that should be in the SDRAM.
Currently I made the buffer static and use  __attribute__((section(".sdram"))) to map it to the SDRAM. However, there are two problems with this approach:

1. The buffer should not be static as it belongs to the object (and I might at some time want to add another such object.)
2. My approach does not work when the class is a template: The __attribute__((section(".sdram"))) is simply ignored.

So: Is there a way, to have a (single) data member of a (template) class reside in another linker section, and how?

I am using the arm-none-eabi-gcc 5.2.0 if that is important, but would probably like to switch to clang later, so solutions for clang are welcome as well.

Best regards,
mox

Comment: Non-static, non-global objects do not exist for a linker. They are allocated at run time either on the stack or on the heap. The linker has nothing to do with them. If you want to place stuff in whatever memory kind at run time, you need to write an allocator that allocates blocks in that kind of memory.

Comment: You also cannot place a single data member at an address away from its owner object. You can have a member that *points* to such a remote memory location.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for the tip about allocators. I will look into that.